# Ordering data before the join to return latest data

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables on a phone number. But I need to make sure it returns the data on the **last** instance of the phone number in the joining table. But it only ever matches and returns the first instance. Obviously I stupidly tried putting the ORDER BY DateAdded Desc at the end. But clearly that didn't work.

```
SELECT `twiliosent`.`ResponseCodeHTTP`, `twiliosent`.`MessageId`, 
`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`, `favoritesheader`.`FirstName`, 
`favoritesheader`.`LastName`, max(`favoritesheader`.`DateAdded`) 
AS DateAdded FROM `twiliosent`  
LEFT JOIN `favoritesheader` ON 
`favoritesheader`.`CellPhone` = (CONCAT (SUBSTRING(`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,1,3), 
    '-', SUBSTRING(`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,4,3), 
    '-', SUBSTRING(`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,7,4))) 
WHERE 
    `twiliosent`.`MessageId` = '5C697ABB-A4F2-5145-8D3A-718BB872DE41' 
    AND `twiliosent`.`StatusText` = 'Success' 
GROUP BY `favoritesheader`.`CellPhone`  
ORDER BY `twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`, DateAdded Desc
```

Comment: Easy in MySQL 8.x, not that easy in MySQL 5.x. Which version do you have?

Comment: We are using 5.7.  #sadface

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the chance of testing this, but you can add an extra outer join to remove all dates that are not the last one.

For example:

```
SELECT `twiliosent`.`ResponseCodeHTTP`, `twiliosent`.`MessageId`, 
`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`, `favoritesheader`.`FirstName`, 
`favoritesheader`.`LastName`, max(`favoritesheader`.`DateAdded`) 
AS DateAdded FROM `twiliosent`  
LEFT JOIN `favoritesheader` ON 
`favoritesheader`.`CellPhone` = (CONCAT (SUBSTRING( 
    `twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,1,3), 
    '-', SUBSTRING(`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,4,3), 
    '-', SUBSTRING(`twiliosent`.`PhoneNumberTo`,7,4))) 
-- add this extra outer join to limit the rows to the last one only
left join (
  select CellPhone, max(DateAdded) as max_date_added
  from favoritesheader
  group by CellPhone
) m on m.CellPhone = f.CellPhone and m.max_date_added = f.DateAdded
-- extra join ends here
WHERE 
    `twiliosent`.`MessageId` = '5C697ABB-A4F2-5145-8D3A-718BB872DE41' 
    AND `twiliosent`.`StatusText` = 'Success'
```

Of course, if you happen to have two rows with the *same* last date, both of them will show up in the result.